# Pass value to C binary through cURL (or FTP)

Tags: c, curl, ftp, telnet, netcat

I've got a web application that I know to be written in C, that's running on a specified IP address and port. I can access the application either with `telnet` or `nc`. With each of those, once connecting I'm prompted for input.

Since I've got a copy of the binary, running it through `strings` and `hd` showed me that the application is looking for a particular string to validate. 
There's a file sitting on that domain that I'd like to access, which I can't seem to do with `telnet` or `nc`, so I'm thinking that either `cURL` or `ftp` would be the better bet here.

However, since the string validation that happens with this running service isn't really a password, I'm not sure how to pass this string value into the service with `cURL` or `ftp`. My gut tells me that I probably need to structure the command as a `POST`, but since this definitely isn't an `HTTP` service, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer, but too long to post as a comment)

when dealing with undocumented custom protocols, telnet/curl/wget is definitely not suitable, and nc is not practical. write your own client.

you say the server is expecting a string? well, maybe you could run a dictionary attack on it, make a client that tries everything in a large dictionary (like [this](https://thepiratebay.org/torrent/8159583/CrackStation.Password.Cracking.Dictionary)?), looking for any non-standard response, and go from there. add any strings you find in the binary too, ofc

if that gets you nowhere, maybe the binary is vulnerable to timing attacks? maybe you can extract a string that it is looking for, through a timing attack

and because you already have the binary, you could run it through a disassembler and study the assembly code, it should reveal both whether or not it's timing-attack vulnerable, and, if the strings are hardcoded, what string it is looking for, albeit, reading compiled assembly code is really difficult.. (game crackers does this all the time for cracking video game copy protections)